# for loop crash when iterating over array of iTunesFileTracks

Tags: objective-c, macos, itunes

New to OS x and objective C. I am getting a crash in my program reported from several users I have not been able to reproduce it on my machine.

```
Feb 22, 2014, 9:06:44 AM: An uncaught exception was raised
Feb 22, 2014, 9:06:44 AM: *** -[NSArray getObjects:range:]: range {3392, 16} extends beyond bounds for empty array
Feb 22, 2014, 9:06:44 AM: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f05541c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff94c12e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ef9bc9f -[NSArray getObjects:range:] + 271
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ef9da63 -[NSArray countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:] + 163
    4   MYAppMac                        0x00000001000037b9 +[ITunesProvider getITunesMediaFiles:] + 5209
```

The line crash line points to this for loop

```
        // Get tracks from iTunesUserPlaylist
        SBElementArray *fileTracks = [list fileTracks];   

        for(iTunesFileTrack* track in fileTracks)
        { 
         // my code here. I do not modify filetracks anywhere in the loop
        }
```

The for loop iterates over the items in the array but at some point it crashes trying to access items further down. I do not modify the fileTracks array at all. Any ideas what's going  on ?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. You're iterating over a live array which is changing on the fly depending on what your users do with iTunes. You could try getting the array using `-get` and iterate over the resulting fixed `NSArray` like this:

```
NSArray* fileTracks = [[list fileTracks] get];
for (iTunesFileTrack* track in fileTracks)
{
    // Your code
}
```